# NSDateFormatter issue while converting NSDate to NSString

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, nsdate, nsdateformatter

`NSDateFormatter` is providing a default date of

```
2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

I need it to format in the format of January, 01 2013 04:00:00

Here is my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM, dd yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *startDt=[_calendarDetailsDict objectForKey:@"dtStart"];
NSDate *endDt=[_calendarDetailsDict objectForKey:@"dtEnd"];
NSString *str=[formatter stringFromDate:startDt];
NSString *str1=[formatter stringFromDate:endDt];
```

Comment: What is your problem in above code? Explain briefly?

Comment: Exactly what do you want to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NSString *dateStr =@"2012-09-15 00:11:59";
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
 NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
 dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM, dd yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
 NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
 NSLog(@"date: %@", dateString);
```

may help u.